# import update to wsus

Tags: wsus

is there any way to download update and import it to wsus ??

Comment: A Windows Update, or a 3rd Party Update?

Comment: its windows update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System Center Update Publisher](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0446cce9-94a4-4fb0-b335-e7516044063d&displaylang=en) will let you publish many 3rd party updates to your own WSUS server. There are requirements for the source package, but [it's all documented clearly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531069.aspx).

Comment: i need to import windows update manually i already download it from internet, is there any way to import it to wsus ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why not just let WSUS download it??

Comment: so there is no way to do that

Answer (score 1):

1. In the WSUS admin console, navigate to the Update Services/WSUSSERVER/Updates tree,
   right-click and click "Import Updates...".
2. Search and find the update.
3. Add to basket.
4. View basket.
5. Check Import directly into Windows Server Updates Services
6. Click Import.
7. The ActiveX performs the API calls to import the metadata and the update to the WSUS installation.

For third party updates, check out [Local Update Publisher](http://www.localupdatepublisher.com).

Source:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939825(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I pick this method over the 3rd party methods. Worked just fine!!